# How to re-register the geofences in device reboot? before user unlock the device(in LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence, google-people-api, geofence

I have tried to re-register the geofences after device reboot.
It perfectly fine with the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED(after user unlock the device).
But it is not working with the ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED(before user unlock the device).
Is there any way to re-register my geofences before user unlock the device?
When I try it gives me the following error.

```
2021-05-25 18:07:30.264 3758-3781/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdatesbackgroundkotlin E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService.START on com.google.android.gms
```